# Method is hanging within function, not sure why

Tags: python, twitter, oauth, bots

Okay, so I'm making a bot framework in python, and I'm having issues with creating a twitter command. I'm not sure how much sense this will make to anyone else, I think I did my best to explain this, so let me know if I can provide anymore information or code.

So, my twitter command looks like this

```
@Command(name="tweets", aliases="tweet")
def tweets(chat, message, args, sender):
    if len(args) == 0:
        chat.SendMessage("Provide a user")
        return

    def get_tweets():
        consumer_key = JakeBot.conf.get_value("twitter_api-key")
        consumer_secret = JakeBot.conf.get_value("twitter_api-secret")
        access_token_key = JakeBot.conf.get_value("twitter_access")
        access_token_secret = JakeBot.conf.get_value("twitter_access-secret")

        api = twitter.Api(consumer_key, consumer_secret, access_token_key, access_token_secret)
        public_tweets = api.GetUserTimeline(api.GetUser(args[0]).id)

        return public_tweets

    print get_tweets()[0].text
```

Now this, is my standard command format, which works for any command.

I call my command by searching by command name and getting the function and calling it in a separate thread like so:

```
    func = commands[command]
    thread.start_new_thread(func, (message.Chat, message.Body, get_args(args), message.Sender))
```

This works for all my other commands like !echo

For reference, I am using the following lib for twitter: https://code.google.com/p/python-twitter/

Now, the problem is that the application 'hangs' on:

```
    api = twitter.Api(consumer_key, consumer_secret, access_token_key, access_token_secret)
```

I load my command modules through a file reader from my commands package, which I don't *think* is my issue here. However, if I just throw this in a quick test module, it works perfectly fine, and prints my latest tweet. Instead, when I call it as stated earlier, it hangs on creating the instance of the twitter API, and I really don't know why, even after hours of debugging this.